# Understand token expiry for Connected APP using JWT authentication

Tags: externalid

The session expiry for an accessToken can be configured at org level, profile level, connected app level. When authenticating via private key certificate using the JWT OAuth Flow, which session expiry is considered?

We are experiencing a strange behaviour: we authenticate using the sfdx-cli and we use the token often, so we would expect it not to expiry. However, after few months it expires anyways

Comment: I had something similar happen to me, took me a minute to realise it was during a Salesforce release. Different use case but if the timelines match...

Answer (score 0):

The precedence here is:
connected app > profile > org-wide

Comment: When the connected app is empty it goes on profile?

Comment: Yes. It takes the value of whatever level that information is defined at, in order of precedence. If not defined on the connected app, it'll look to see if it's defined at the profile level. If it's not defined there either, it'll use the org-wide value.